# How to check if filename contains digits within an if condition

Tags: bash, if-statement, digits

In the following script I match files consisting of numbers 0-9 in the pattern "Buchung_cdate_[0-9].pdf":

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/home/benji/Nextcloud/Buchhaltung/test/"
tag="Buchung"
images="(*.png|*.jpg|*.jpeg|*.JPG|*.JPEG|*.webp)"
#convert="convert $f "Buchung_cdate.pdf""

#Preperations
shopt -s extglob

#Actual script starting here – do not change unless you know what you are doing ;)
for f in $dir*$images; do #loop on every file that has extension $images
    if [[ "$f" != *$tag* ]]; then #exclude files of the loop with filename including $tag
      cdate="$(date -r "$f" +"%Y-%"m"-%"d)"
      if [[ -f $dir"Buchung_$cdate.pdf" ]]; then #checks if "Buchung_$cdate.pdf" matches an already existing file in $dir
        if [ -f $dir"Buchung_$cdate"_[0-9].pdf ]; then
          echo $f" - Already existing!"
        else
          echo $f" - Already existing! Convert!"
        fi
      #echo $f" - Already existing!"
      else
      echo $f" - cdate not equal --> convert to \"Buchung_cdate.pdf\"!"
    fi
    else
      echo $f" - I include \"Buchung\" in my filename - Do nothing"
    fi
done
```

But what I really want is, to check if there is any number in place and raise this number by 1. (Like in the usecase when copying files a.pdf to a_1.pdf, a_3.pdf, … )

Any hints how to solve this?

See above. I already tried it with `[0-9]` but that is not what I am searching for.

Comment: Please [edit] the title to reflect the actual question. Check out [ask] if you want tips on that. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Comment: I do not really know what you mean. The script runs perfectly but the question is about the digit and how to address them in this context…

Comment: I checked your link but that does not answer the question here: I am talking about matching digits within the if condition in bash not extracting it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to know whether there is a file where the name starts with `$dir"Buchung_$cdate"_` and followed by a digit. Correct? Since the number of files can be 0, 1 or several, I would create first an array with all files matching this pattern, and then test the size of this array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the end I wanted to know if there is a way to tell bash if there is a digit in a certain place or not and if this is the case than raise it by one. I have solved the following way:
`collisions="$(ls "$dir" | grep "$mdate")"
          max=$(echo ${collisions//@($tag|$mdate|$format|_)} | tr " " "\n" | sort -nr | head -1)
          suffix=$(expr $max + 1)`
But I think there is a more delicate way to do this…